# formData object sent with jQuery ajax to server returns empty array on success

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, windows-server-2012

the title basically says it all.

I am collecting some data and appending it into the formData object in order to POST it to my PHP file and handle the rest there.

My Ajax function:

```
save.addEventListener("click", function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    getAllContents();
    console.log(updateObj);

    updateObj = JSON.stringify(updateObj);
    console.log(updateObj);

    $.ajax({
        url: "test.php",
        type: "POST",
        data: updateObj,
        success: function(response){
            console.log("Success: ", response);
        },
        error: function(response){
            console.log("Error: ", response);
        }
    });
});
```

The updateObj contains everything which I appended to the formData Object. The console log of this variable returns everything. So the problem must be right in the ajax POST.

**Update** The content of console.log(updateObj) :

```
[{"row_id":1,"status":"Anmeldung","ma_name":"AA","datum":"/","fa1":"testname1","fa2":"testname2","limit":"10.000","gruppe_kredit":"/","omv_kdnr":"8124213","sap_kdnr":"/","fos":"/","hga_kdnr":"/"},{"row_id":3,"status":"Anmeldung","ma_name":"AA","datum":"/","fa1":"ame1","fa2":"name2","limit":"12.000","gruppe_kredit":"/","omv_kdnr":"81515616","sap_kdnr":"/","fos":"/","hga_kdnr":"/"},{"row_id":2,"status":"Kunde","ma_name":"AA","datum":"/","fa1":"newname1","fa2":"newname2","limit":"15.323","gruppe_kredit":"/","omv_kdnr":"81515616","sap_kdnr":"/","fos":"/","hga_kdnr":"/"}]
```

My PHP File only contains a `print_r` of the `$_POST`

```
<?php 
   print_r($_POST);
?>
```

This is what my success function of the ajax call logs :

```
success:  Array
(
)
```

**UPDATE2**

This is how my formData Object gets filled in :

```
// console.log($test.length);
var updateObj = [];

function getAllContents(){
    var $tableTr = $('tbody tr');
    updateObj = [];

    $tableTr.each(function(index, element){
        var $row_id = $(this).data("rowid");
        // console.log("ID in Table: " + $row_id);
        var status = $(this).find('#status option:selected').val();
        // console.log("ID "+$row_id+" in der Table hat den Status: "+status);
        var ma_name = $(this).find('#ma-name').val();
        // console.log(ma_name);
        var datum = $(this).find('#datum').val();
        // console.log(datum);
        var firmenname1 = $(this).find('#firmenname1').val();
        // console.log(firmenname1);
        var firmenname2 = $(this).find('#firmenname2').val();
        // console.log(firmenname2);
        var limit = $(this).find('#limit').val();
        // console.log(limit);
        var gruppe_kredit = $(this).find('#gruppe_kredit').val();
        // console.log(gruppe_kredit);
        var omv_kdnr = $(this).find('#omv_kdnr').val();
        // console.log(omv_kdnr);
        var sap_kdnr = $(this).find('#sap_kdnr').val();
        // console.log(sap_kdnr);
        var fos = $(this).find('#fos').val();
        // console.log(fos);
        var hga_kdnr = $(this).find('#fos').val();
        // console.log(hga_kdnr);

        var pushObj = {
                        row_id: $row_id,
                        status: status,
                        ma_name: ma_name,
                        datum: datum,
                        fa1: firmenname1,
                        fa2: firmenname2,
                        limit: limit,
                        gruppe_kredit: gruppe_kredit,
                        omv_kdnr: omv_kdnr,
                        sap_kdnr: sap_kdnr,
                        fos: fos,
                        hga_kdnr: hga_kdnr
                    };

        updateObj.push(pushObj);
        // PushObjekt mit Inhalt befüllen und das PushObjekt ins updateObjekt einbetten

        //console.log(updateObj);
    });
}

 getAllContents();
```

Comment: before calling ajax, you have `console.log()`. is that giving expected result??

Comment: Yes the console.log is giving me the expected result.

Comment: check in console for ajax request

Comment: The ajax request properly calls the test.php target. The result or its print_r of $_POST is still empty though

Comment: I checked your code it works on my side.

Comment: May be you can provide your updateObj

Comment: I have updated my Question with the output

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Problem is that you are trying to send an array of JS objects. in this case normal `JSON.stringify(obj)` won't work as there are no keys on the individual objects so the object wouldn't get encoded properly into a string so on server end it won't be parsed properly and wonldn't get passed to the `$_POST`. One solution could be

```
updateObj = [{"row_id":1,"status":"Anmeldung","ma_name":"AA","datum":"/","fa1":"testname1","fa2":"testname2","limit":"10.000","gruppe_kredit":"/","omv_kdnr":"8124213","sap_kdnr":"/","fos":"/","hga_kdnr":"/"},{"row_id":3,"status":"Anmeldung","ma_name":"AA","datum":"/","fa1":"ame1","fa2":"name2","limit":"12.000","gruppe_kredit":"/","omv_kdnr":"81515616","sap_kdnr":"/","fos":"/","hga_kdnr":"/"},{"row_id":2,"status":"Kunde","ma_name":"AA","datum":"/","fa1":"newname1","fa2":"newname2","limit":"15.323","gruppe_kredit":"/","omv_kdnr":"81515616","sap_kdnr":"/","fos":"/","hga_kdnr":"/"}];
        // window.updateObj =
    console.log(updateObj);
    Obj = {};
    $.each(updateObj,function(x,obj){ Obj[""+x] = obj;});
    // updateObj = JSON.stringify(updateObj);
    updateObj = JSON.stringify(Obj);
    console.log(Obj);

$.ajax({
        url: "//localhost:80/test/",
        type: "POST",
        data: updateObj,
        success: function(response){
            console.log("Success: ", response);
        },
        error: function(response){
            console.log("Error: ", response);
        }
    });
```

------------------------update----------------------

You can also do it like this but it'll be a bit tricky to decode on the server size I guess.

```
updateObj = [{"row_id":1,"status":"Anmeldung","ma_name":"AA","datum":"/","fa1":"testname1","fa2":"testname2","limit":"10.000","gruppe_kredit":"/","omv_kdnr":"8124213","sap_kdnr":"/","fos":"/","hga_kdnr":"/"},{"row_id":3,"status":"Anmeldung","ma_name":"AA","datum":"/","fa1":"ame1","fa2":"name2","limit":"12.000","gruppe_kredit":"/","omv_kdnr":"81515616","sap_kdnr":"/","fos":"/","hga_kdnr":"/"},{"row_id":2,"status":"Kunde","ma_name":"AA","datum":"/","fa1":"newname1","fa2":"newname2","limit":"15.323","gruppe_kredit":"/","omv_kdnr":"81515616","sap_kdnr":"/","fos":"/","hga_kdnr":"/"}];
    console.log(updateObj);
    Obj = {};
    Obj["updateObj"] = updateObj;
    updateObj = JSON.stringify(Obj);
    $.ajax({
            url: "//localhost:80/test/",
            type: "POST",
            data: updateObj,
            success: function(response){
                console.log("Success: ", response);
            },
            error: function(response){
                console.log("Error: ", response);
            }
        });
```

**----------update2.0**

```
updateObj = [{"row_id":1,"status":"Anmeldung","ma_name":"AA","datum":"/","fa1":"testname1","fa2":"testname2","limit":"10.000","gruppe_kredit":"/","omv_kdnr":"8124213","sap_kdnr":"/","fos":"/","hga_kdnr":"/"},{"row_id":3,"status":"Anmeldung","ma_name":"AA","datum":"/","fa1":"ame1","fa2":"name2","limit":"12.000","gruppe_kredit":"/","omv_kdnr":"81515616","sap_kdnr":"/","fos":"/","hga_kdnr":"/"},{"row_id":2,"status":"Kunde","ma_name":"AA","datum":"/","fa1":"newname1","fa2":"newname2","limit":"15.323","gruppe_kredit":"/","omv_kdnr":"81515616","sap_kdnr":"/","fos":"/","hga_kdnr":"/"}];
        // window.updateObj =
    console.log(updateObj);
    Obj = {};


    var Obj = updateObj.reduce(function(o, v, i) {
       o[i] = v;
       return o;
    }, {});
    updateObj = JSON.stringify(Obj);
    console.log(Obj);

$.ajax({
        url: "//localhost:80/test/",
        type: "POST",
        data: updateObj,
        success: function(response){
            console.log("Success: ", response);
        },
        error: function(response){
            console.log("Error: ", response);
        }
    });
```

Comment: Weirdly enough the solution of you doesnt work any more. Empty response again

Comment: your updateObj must have changed or the obj is not formatted properly.

Comment: The updateObj is still the same. Like in my update in my question

Comment: normally the formData is primarily a single formatted JS hash/object so its easy to encode it into a JSON, but in your case its an array of hashes/objects and that so without a key.

Comment: which one are you trying to? the former or the later?

Comment: The Former. I have updated my Question with the code how I fill in the formData Object in case it's wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Try with parameter json if you want to get response in json format  **[Edit]**

```
save.addEventListener("click", function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        getAllContents();
        console.log(updateObj);

        updateObj = JSON.stringify(updateObj);
        console.log(updateObj);

        $.ajax({
            url: "test.php",
            type: "POST",
            dataType: "json",
            data: ({data:updateObj}),
            success: function(response){
                console.log("Success: ", response);
            },
            error: function(response){
                console.log("Error: ", response);
            }
        });
    });
```

and on server side

> parse_str($_POST['data'],$data);
>        echo json_encode($data);exit;

Comment: Tried it out. The result of that echo is still empty.

Comment: the content or how it gets generated?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/92356/discussion-between-minesh-patel-and-noa-dev).

Answer (score 0):

Try This-
at ajax call-

```
   $.ajax({
            url: "test.php",
            type: "POST",
            dataType: "json",
            data: updateObj,
            success: function(response){
                console.log("Success: ", response);
            },
            error: function(response){
                console.log("Error: ", response);
            }
```

**At Php**

```
<?php 
   echo json_encode($_POST,true);
?>
```